# Can I authenticate the client accessing my API gateway using TLS-PSK?

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-api-gateway

I created an API Gateway to allow a certain client to access specific routes in my app engine. The client prefers to authenticate using Pre-Shared Key (PSK) over TLS. Is it possible to do that in a Google API gateway?

Comment: I have provided an answer below to your question. Please check

Answer (score 1):

With the GCP API gateway, you have a limited number of built-in authentication methods. I don’t think we can authenticate using Pre-Shared Key (PSK) over TLS. In order to authenticate using the GCP API Gateway you have to use one of the alternate authentication methods provided in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/authentication-method).If you think it is valid request for GCP API gateway you may raise a Feature request at [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues)